# How to parse the Object in JSON type

Tags: java, json, class

I have a JSON file and I do not know how can I parse the part of "coordinates", others done already. It seems null, others seem ok when I try to reach them. I guess, coordinates part is another class defined in cities part. Could you please help me to get coordinates of cities?

I kept my cities in a linkedlist.

```
 "cities" : [
            {
                "code" : "SCL" ,
                "name" : "Santiago" ,
                "country" : "CL" ,
                "continent" : "South America" ,
                "timezone" : -4 ,
                "coordinates" : {"S" : 33, "W" : 71} ,
                "population" : 6000000 ,
                "region" : 1
            } 




static List<City> allCities = new LinkedList<City>();
static List<Flight> allFlights = new LinkedList<Flight>();
static JSONArray cities;
static JSONArray flights;

FileReader reader = new FileReader("csair.json");
JSONObject CSAirData = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(reader);
cities  = (JSONArray) CSAirData.get("cities");
flights  = (JSONArray) CSAirData.get("routes");
```

Comment: In the above listing, "cities" appears to be an element of a Map/JSONObject for which you failed to include the enclosing `{ }` characters.  (And you also omitted the closing `]` for the array.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "cities" is an attribute of variable myVar, like this

```
var myVar = {
  "cities": [
    {
      "code": "SCL",
      "name": "Santiago",
      ...
    }
  ]
};
```

then you could access "coordinates" by doing

```
myVar.cities[0].coordinates
```

- "cities" corresponds to an array
- the first element in the array (index = 0) is an object
- that object has an attribute called "coordinates", which references another object

**Edit**

Now that I see you are using Java code, you just need to transform this syntax into Java.

We know that "cities" is a JSONArray.

```
JSONObject city = cities.get(0);  // Get the first city in the array (index = 0)
JSONObject coordinates = city.getJSONObject("coordinates");
int coordinates_s = coordinates.getInt("S");
int coordinates_w = coordinates.getInt("W");
```

Comment: I dont understand what myVar is. For example, I need to show coordinates of each city. I could not fix it yet.

Comment: It looks like your code is part of a larger piece of code in which there was a variable assignment. What variable is holding this "cities":  [ ... information?

Comment: @user139518, I've added Java syntax to my answer.